# How do I get a list of pairs instead of pair of lists from macOS Reminders via AppleScript

Tags: list, applescript, reminders

The following AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set rems to {name, name of container} of
        (every reminder whose completed is true and name contains "Turkey")
        as list
end tell

return rems
```

Returns:

```
{
{"Turkey sausage", "Turkey 1/2 pound regular sliced", "1lb Sliced Turkey", "1 pound of sliced turkey", "1 pound of sliced turkey", "1lb sliced turkey", "Turkey", "1 pound of sliced turkey", "Turkey sausage", "1lb sliced turkey", "1/2lb Sliced turkey", "Sliced turkey￼", "1 pound of sliced turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Frozen turkey sausage", "Sliced turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey meatballs", "Frozen turkey sausage", "Turkey slices"},
{"Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Grocery", "Lockport Shopping"}
}
```

...which is a pair of lists.  Is there a way to structure the one-line query in such a way that it instead returns:

```
{{"Turkey sausage", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey 1/2 pound regular sliced", "Grocery"},
{"1lb Sliced Turkey", "Grocery"},
{"1 pound of sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"1 pound of sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"1lb sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey", "Grocery"},
{"1 pound of sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey sausage", "Grocery"},
{"1lb sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"1/2lb Sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Sliced turkey￼", "Grocery"},
{"1 pound of sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Frozen turkey sausage", "Grocery"},
{"Sliced turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey meatballs", "Grocery"},
{"Frozen turkey sausage", "Grocery"},
{"Turkey slices""Grocery"}}
```

instead?

Note, I'm not asking how to manipulate the returned pair of lists list into a list of pairs list on subsequent lines of code - I can do that.  I'm just wondering if there's a way to get back what I want by changing the 1 line of code.

Comment: Short anse=wer: you can't. Apps return lists in the format they are programmed to return lists, and there's no built-in function in AppleScript to do what amounts to a set transform.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, but I don't know the language well enough to determine it's not possible. I was hoping there was some trick to coerce it... I wrote a repeat over lunch to do the transform.

Answer (score 0):

First, I should point out that the reason OP (I) was using `{name, name of container} of` in the command is because it is orders of magnitude faster than simply retrieving `every reminder...`.  This, is SLOOOOWWWW...

```
    set rems to (every reminder whose completed is true and name contains "Turkey")
        as list
```

Every time I have tried to run it, I end up canceling the script after about 3 minutes.  It goes so slow because I have a very large Reminders database (172 incomplete currently and decades worth of completed reminders).  And in Apple's wisdom, every reminder you ever create remains in the database forever. ... which makes scripting reminders slower and slower day by day.

As to the question, while you cannot modify the 1 line to get a list of pairs quickly, you can get a list of full records (in a structure similar to what's desired) in roughly the same time as it takes to run the provided example.

This will run in about the same time:

```
    set rems to properties of (every reminder whose completed is true and name contains "Turkey")
        as list
```

With my large database, the above runs in roughly 53 seconds.  In fact, in my test, it ran faster than the original code (which took a minute, 14).

Each item is a record, not a list of names, list of lists, etc..  I.e. it looks like:

```
{{name, list, due, ...},
 {name, list, due, ...},
 ...}
```

It just contains more than 2 attributes in every sublist.  And instead of indexing by a numeric index, you can index by name.

Then you can use the list like this:

```
    repeat with rem in rems
        set theName to name of rem as string
        set theList to name of container of rem as string

        ...

    end repeat
```